# How can I set up multicast tunnel between hosts on the same net

Tags: multicast

Dealing with AWS, where multicast packets won't travel even between systems on the same net (VPC). Generally, this is not specific to AWS, as this is generally possible in any network (i.e. you have a switch that sinks multicast for some reason).

I'm trying to remedy this with mrouted. But mrouted just won't allow to establish tunnels on the same network, as it seems to truly believe that it's unnecessary.

Is there a way to do this with mrouted (or with something better), or should I just try to hack mrouted and override that same net tunnel prevention?